# How can I install danshell, a cross-compiled program, on Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, compiling

I'm trying to install this shell: https://sourceforge.net/projects/danshell/
http://danshell.sourceforge.net

And it is saying that it is cross-compiled on Linux and Windows. I am kind of a noob and am not super familiar with cross compilation. I can't for the life of me understand how to install it once I have zipped the download into a new directory. The files I get in the directory are as following:

```
autocomplete.cpp     COPYING.txt        linux.h            sizeof.exe
autocomplete.h       danshell.exe       ls.cpp             utils.cpp
cat.cpp              danshell.ico       ls.exe             utils.h
cat.exe              danshell_v2.0.zip (http://danshell_v2.0.zip/)  main.cpp           welcome_screen.txt
cd.cpp               echo.cpp           main.h             yes.cpp
cd.exe               echo.exe           notes_v.2.0.txt    yes.exe
changelog_v.2.0.txt  License.txt        screenie_v2.0.PNG
computername.txt     linux.cpp          sizeof.cpp
```

With it not being that well documented it is not obvious for me what to do from here. I am on Ubuntu Gnu/Linux. If anyone here is more familiar with cross-compilation knows what to do, I would gladly appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to see how a simple shell works I have one It does not 
have as many features, but is simple, and tiny (104 lines including makefile) It relies on external programs like most Unix shells. It has a make file, so should be easy to build. It should also be easy to extend: E.g. add a `cd` command (the only command that has to be built in), add redirection, … It can be found at https://bitbucket.org/mr_delorenzi_teacher/mush

Answer (score 2):

**Cross-compiling** being generally reserved to the process of building an executable from some source code on one computer in order for the executable to be run on another computer of some different architecture. For example on an x86_64 system build code to be run on an ARM architecture) I think you should read **portable**.

Big Fat Warning : The code seems rather old. No release since (2008)

From the reading of changelog_v2.0.txt included in the zip file, one can notice :

> (just compile and link linux.cpp if you're using Linux).

In the absence of any sort of makefile all we can do is obeing to that instruction. I suggest you simply try a simple basic compilation (with your pwd set to the directory where you unzipped the downloded sources) :

```
gcc -c -o danshell linux.cpp
```

And see what happens and eventually report here the ouput. (BTW I won't try :-P)

Comment: The `notes_v.2.0.txt` file gives recipe `g++ autocomplete.cpp linux.cpp main.cpp utils.cpp -o danshell` however that fails for me because of an undeclared `strerror` (perhaps `<cstring>` needs to be `#include`d in `utils.h`?

Comment: @steeldriver :  You are correct if, as far as I understand, you want to also build misc utilities & features. I had wanted to start simply with only one file in order to discover the major issues. That being said, what is the cpp file generating that error ?

Comment: ... it's in `utils.cpp`

Comment: @steeldriver Anyway, if strerror is said undeclared, it means that some include file is missing. But I think that it'd be more <string.h> than <cstring>. And I'd prefer adding it as part of the .cpp calling strerror than in some other header.

Comment: @steeldriver : Had not seen your last comment : so yes indeed ! retry after adding the #include <string.h> to utils.cpp

Comment: @steeldriver : And yes you can complaint regarding me preferring string.h to cstring in c++ code. In quite old c++ code. ;-)